# Property 'error' does not exist on type '{} | user | error'

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  type user = {
    id: number,
    token: string
  }

  type errorObject = {
    error: string
  }

  interface authState {
      user: user | {} | errorObject,
  }

  const initialState: authState = {
      user: {}
  }

  const error : errorObject = {"error": "hi"}

  initialState.user = error

  console.log(initialState.user.error) // Property 'error' does not exist on type '{} | user | error'.
```

Why does this error? It has an error property so why does it say it doesn't exist? I'm confused.

My goal was to make the user object to be any of these types:

```
user = {} 
// or
user = {"id": number, "token": "1234"}
// or
user = {"error": "error"}
```

Comment: Give a try `initialState.user['error']`

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"error"' can't be used to index type '{} | errorObject'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type '{} | errorObject'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type is pretty broad, the compiler is throwing an error becuase the property may not be present in the paramter.

If you are certain that in a given circumstances the error property would exist, you can use a type assertion.

Ex. `(initialState.user as errorObject).error`

Or if you are not certain of that, you could create your own user defined type guard, for instance:

```
function instanceOfErrorObject(data: user | {} | errorObject): data is errorObject {
    return data.hasOwnProperty("error");
}
```

if you call this function before trying to access error property, compiler will know that it's of an appropriate type:

```
const user = initialState.user;
if (instanceOfErrorObject(user)) console.log(user.error);
```

Comment: the last example is what I need but how do I get this function ? `instanceOfErrorObject(user)`. Cannot find name 'instanceOfErrorObject'

Comment: What do you mean? I literally defined it in the code block above